# Why am I getting derivative of f(x) = x**2, where x = 2, as 0 instead of 4?

Tags: math, sympy, derivative

- I get correct derivative of f(x) = x**2 as 2*x
- However, when I substitute the value of x with 2, it gives 0 as result instead of 4
- Whatever value I am giving to x, it gives 0 as a result

[snapshot of Google Colab notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEO69.png)

I tried this:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
f = x**2

diff(f.subs(x,2), x)
```

I was expecting 4 as a result but I get 0

Comment: But what, looking at that code, made you expect 4, based on knowing what sympy's `diff` does, and what `subs` does, and the order you've put things in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're taking a derivative of a constant. You should derive the function of `f = x**2` first and then substitute `x = 2` to the result afterward. Try something like:

```
diff(f, x).subs(x, 2)
```

or

```
df = diff(f, x)
df.subs(x, 2)
```